# node and res.send a nested array

Tags: json, node.js, express

Have a quite complex array, well, not super complex, but it contains a tree structure. 
Each entry contains of
 name: 
 level:
 url:
 parent:
 children:

Where each entries "children" can contain multiple sub entries. 
So for example, an initial entry may look as

```
> tree = [ 
>     0 [ name: "yourtree", level: 0, url: "www.db.com/0/yourtree", parent: "", children: [ 
>        0 [ name: "first", level: 1, url: "www.db.com/1/first", parent: "yourtree", children: []] 
>        1 [ name: "second", level: 1, url: "www.db.com/1/second", parent: "yourtree", children: []] ......
```

My issues is, that if I try to use JSON.stringify I get an empty array it seems, if I use res.send(tree) no data is sent. So how can I convert a nested array to JSON to send it?

========= Update on structure ==============
OK, so by adding some console.log statements, I managed to extract a live example of the data. 
It is only level one and two of the data though:

```
    console.log("Returning " + tree)
    console.log( tree[0].children );
    res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(tree));


Returning FinTech
[ [ name: 'FinTech',
    level: '0',
    parent: 'FinTech',
    group: 'FinTech',
    children: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ] ]
[ [ name: 'FinTech/IT Process Management',
    level: '1',
    parent: 'FinTech',
    group: 'FinTech',
    children: [ [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object] ] ],
  [ name: 'FinTech/Disruptive Technologies',
    level: '1',
    parent: 'FinTech',
    group: 'FinTech',
    children: [ [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object] ] ],
  [ name: 'FinTech/Technology Risk',
    level: '1',
    parent: 'FinTech',
    group: 'FinTech',
    children: [ [Object], [Object] ] ],
  [ name: 'FinTech/Vendor Products',
    level: '1',
    parent: 'FinTech',
    group: 'FinTech',
    children: [] ],
  [ name: 'FinTech/Technology Change Methodologies',
    level: '1',
    parent: 'FinTech',
    group: 'FinTech',
    children: [ [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object] ] ] ]
```

============= The working model (object of objects rather than array of arrays) ====

```
{ '0': 
   { name: 'FMP',
     level: '0',
     parent: 'FMP',
     group: 'FMP',
     children: 
      { '0': [Object],
        '1': [Object],
        '2': [Object],
        '3': [Object],
        '4': [Object],
        '5': [Object],
        '6': [Object],
        '7': [Object],
        '8': [Object],
        '9': [Object],
        '10': [Object],
        '11': [Object] } } }
{ '0': 
   { name: 'FMP/Private Funds',
     level: '1',
     parent: 'FMP',
     group: 'FMP',
     children: { '0': [Object], '1': [Object], '2': [Object] } },
  '1': 
   { name: 'FMP/Public Funds',
     level: '1',
     parent: 'FMP',
     group: 'FMP',
     children:
```

Comment: why not use res.json() to send the whole array?

Comment: Tried, no luck, it just sends an empty reply ([])

Comment: shoulnd this `res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(tree));` use JSON.stringify?

Comment: is your data a JSON string or an JS Array variable?

Comment: Its an array, or technically an array of arrays (of arrays of arrays), and it is id value pairs, but it does not translate as it, I.E. you can access it as tree[0].name and you would get FinTech from the examples about, but its not coming up as [object object] pair, not certain why.

Comment: I think the issue is that for whatever reason, JSON.stringyfi (or parse) does not like the array of array structures. but I can not figure out why or what I can do about it.

Comment: OK, in the end I had to change the structure of the data completely to get an object of objects instead of an array of arrays. Not certain exactly why JSON.stringify likes one but not the other, but it does seem like it. Have added example output of the object that works. Can't think of any painless way of doing a deepcopy from array of arrays to object of objects.

Comment: Think the issue is that JSON demands that there is a index data pair, where as arrays does not get an index if you use push. May be that this is more a javascript compilation question, but my guess would be that if you call myArray[0] it expects that you want the first array, where as if you ask for myObject[0] it expects that you want the object with the index "0"?